# Writing to and reading from owstimer config file

Tags: 2007, development, configuration

My question is regarding writing to and reading from owstimer configuration file.

Could anyone provide any of examples how to do so? I tried searching but didn't find any good examples.

Also to note it is my own configuration, my own structure will be ...

Waiting for response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming that you are using this for a custom timer job. There is an article here that explains it in further detail but essentially your code would look like this:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]
```

Here is a couple articles for further explanation.
http://doitwithsharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/03/config-file-for-sharepoint-custom-timer.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686(v=office.12).aspx